# Change CSS of element not in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have an element, let's say a circle.
And there is a list of item in a list view.
Initially, the circle is not rendered. I have set its CSS `display` property to `none`, and instead `select an item` message is displayed. The idea is when the user selects an item from the list, I want to show the circle changing its `background-color` property associated with selected item.

My approach is something like this

```
itemSelected(item) {
   const itemtColor = item.color;
   $('#selected-item-color').css('background-color', itemColor);
}
```

The issue is:

As the element is not present in the DOM when I try `$('#selected-item-color')`, it will return an empty list, and the change of property does not do anything. But on next subsequent selections, it works fine.

So, is there any clean way to do this before the element is actually rendered in the DOM either jQuery or JavaScript. Or, should I just look for a way to do this after the element is rendered, which I'm not sure if there is a way with my problem.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**

I have the HTML code written in `handlebars`

The code calling above function

```
<div class="item-list-content">
    {{#each itemList as |item|}}
        <div class="list-item" {{action "itemSelected" item}}>{{item.name}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

The dynamic content

```
<div class="item-details">
    {{#if selecteditem}}
       <div id="selected-item-color"></div>
    {{else}}
      <div class="item-details-message">Please select an item</div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the element is not in the DOM tree? The DOM tree and the layout tree are two separate things. display: none only removes an element from the latter.

Comment: Yeah I checked the tree structure. And that was intended. As i have a message that shows up initially instead of the element.

Comment: Also change the css when element is going to show (that means on change of select)

Comment: Yeah, the list is always displayed. Each selection results in different bgColor for the circle element. The above function `itemSelected(item)` is called on `click` with `item` object passed as parameter.

Comment: @Samuel Liew, just did.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can just use ngShow instead of ngIf. There are better ways to do that as well, but for your issue ngShow will solve your problem.

Comment: `ngIf/ngShow`, sounds like you are talking of angular.js, but I'm not using it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out few things and could not get anything to solve this.

So, I ended up doing the next best thing:
Putting the code to change project color inside a timeout function.
A timeout of 1ms worked for me, however I have not tested it well, and to be on a safer side, an interval of 10ms should work without problems.

[setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)